# Using ACF fields to populate a CF7 select box based off repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7

Ive looked through a few posts and I'm struggling to find a solution to my ACF + CF7 problem.

I want users to be able to add dates into ACF field in the backend of my custom post. I will then have a shortcode in my contact form that creates this dropdown list. This then should create a drop down list of those dates, populated from the ACf repeater, for anyone on the front end to choose.

I have an ACF repeater field called course_dates that has sub-fields called date-of-choice. The post type is training-course & the select box in the CF7 form is date-selector.

Does anyone have a solution to creating this? I've tried with dynamic CF7 plugins but I can't get anything to work with ACF correctly.

```php
function dynamic_select_field_values($scanned_tag, $replace)
{
    if ($scanned_tag['name'] != 'date-selector') return $scanned_tag;

    $rows = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'training-course',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        )
    );

    if (!$rows) return $scanned_tag;

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $repeater_values = get_field('course-dates', $row->ID, false);

        if ($repeater_values) {
            foreach ($repeater_values as $repeater_item) {
                $scanned_tag['raw_values'][] = $repeater_item['date-of-choice'] . '|' . $repeater_item['date-of-choice'];
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($scanned_tag['raw_values'])) {
        $pipes = new WPCF7_Pipes($scanned_tag['raw_values']);
        $scanned_tag['values'] = $pipes->collect_befores();
        $scanned_tag['pipes'] = $pipes;
    }

    return $scanned_tag;
}

add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag', 'dynamic_select_field_values', 10, 2);
```

Shortcode:

```
[radio date-selector use_label_element default:1]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Can you update your question with the code you have written so far?

Comment: Apologies, edited it now

Comment: so is the `$sanned_tag['raw_values'][]` being returned popuated with your list of options?